# Outlook 2010 hyperlink to Public Folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, hyperlink

In previous versions of OL I used to be able to send links to public folders. But now the root public folder name contains the user's email address, as in:

```
Outlook:\\Public Folders - b.gates@ms.com\All Public Folders...
```

So when I send a link to someone I need to put their email address there. Is there some other way of creating the link without the email address?

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer to this if anyone knows....